# Как в ES-2015 из массива аргументов сделать последовательность численных аргументов

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Доброго времени суток

Есть гипотетическая функция которая преобразовывает массив аргументов в последовательность численных аргументов, как её правильно реализовать, чтобы она работала?

```
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ru", {
          year: "2-digit",
          month: "2-digit",
          day: "2-digit"
        });

var arr = [2014, 0, 1];

function formatDate(...array) {
return formatter.format(...array/*преобразовали ..array в = 2014, 0, 1*/);
}
formatDate([2014, 0, 1]); // Функция преобразовала в formatDate(2014, 0, 1) и получили на выхоже  return 01.01.14
```

Буду благодарен если поможете разобраться

Comment: код который в вопросе что показывает? как есть или как хотелось? в функции `formatDate` параметр _array_, а передается _date_

Comment: Прошу прощения, для большей ясности поправил. Код который в вопросе - это как хотелось бы, он не валидный.

Comment: предыдущий комментарий был к тому, что если б в коде было заменено date. на array или наоборот, то все заработало бы

Comment: Так в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: вот тут многоточие убери _formatDate(...array)_

Comment: Спасибо большое, дошло, чтобы spread"ом развернуть массив, нужно троеточие не указывать в фукнции, а в возврате его указать.

Comment: я верен на 100% что вы неверно используете _Intl.DateTimeFormat_ - что это и как именно должен выглядеть вызов команды _format_ для него?

Comment: удалил комментарий, значит все починилось?

Comment: Да, я чтобы корректно в дату преобразовать забыл добавить new Date(...array);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение `...` зависит от того где они используются.

При вызове функций

```
f(...iterableObj);
```

В литералах массива:

```
[...iterableObj, 4, 5, 6]
```

При деструктивном присваивании:

```
[a, b, ...iterableObj] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Это будет распознано как [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

В случае же использования его в определении функции - это будет распознано как [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Таким образом, для кода в вопросе нужно убрать `...` из определения

```
function formatDate(array) {
    return formatter.format(...array/*преобразовали ..array в = 2014, 0, 1*/);
}
```